# Which controller should I buy for a SCSI-3 tape drive?

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, scsi

I have a HP StorageWorks Ultrium 960, which have a SCSI-3 interface.

It is a quite old tape drive, so which SCSI controller should I buy?

**Update**

It is for PCI or PCI-X and the server is running RHEL 5.6.

Comment: You need to tell us what bus type you need and what OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13572_na/13572_na.html

If you have a PCI Express port in your server, you should use: 412911-B21

If you only have PCI-X slots, use: 374654-B21